# Why does the require_valid_user parameter keeps promping user authentification?

Tags: couchdb

So my problem is :

Whenever I set the `require_valid_user` to `true` in my CouchDB configuration, it will prompt me to enter my user and password every times I authenticate.

The problem occurs only when I try to use the *_utils/*. When I do a curl request, I get a positive response.

**TESTS**

Curl Request : Positive
Mozilla /_utils/ : Problem occurs
Google Chrome /_utils/ : Problem still occurs

I can't figure out the problem. If you have any hints it would be appreciated. Thank you!

**Config**

```
{
  "httpd_design_handlers": {
    "_compact": "{couch_mrview_http, handle_compact_req}",
    "_info": "{couch_mrview_http, handle_info_req}",
    "_list": "{couch_mrview_show, handle_view_list_req}",
    "_rewrite": "{couch_httpd_rewrite, handle_rewrite_req}",
    "_show": "{couch_mrview_show, handle_doc_show_req}",
    "_update": "{couch_mrview_show, handle_doc_update_req}",
    "_view": "{couch_mrview_http, handle_view_req}"
  },
  "uuids": {
    "algorithm": "sequential",
    "max_count": "1000"
  },
  "stats": {
    "rate": "1000",
    "samples": "[0, 60, 300, 900]"
  },
  "cors": {
    "credentials": "true",
    "headers": "accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer, x-csrf-token",
    "methods": "GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE",
    "origins": "*"
  },
  "httpd_global_handlers": {
    "/": "{couch_httpd_misc_handlers, handle_welcome_req, <<\"Welcome\">>}",
    "_active_tasks": "{couch_httpd_misc_handlers, handle_task_status_req}",
    "_all_dbs": "{couch_httpd_misc_handlers, handle_all_dbs_req}",
    "_config": "{couch_httpd_misc_handlers, handle_config_req}",
    "_db_updates": "{couch_dbupdates_httpd, handle_req}",
    "_log": "{couch_httpd_misc_handlers, handle_log_req}",
    "_oauth": "{couch_httpd_oauth, handle_oauth_req}",
    "_plugins": "{couch_plugins_httpd, handle_req}",
    "_replicate": "{couch_replicator_httpd, handle_req}",
    "_restart": "{couch_httpd_misc_handlers, handle_restart_req}",
    "_session": "{couch_httpd_auth, handle_session_req}",
    "_stats": "{couch_httpd_stats_handlers, handle_stats_req}",
    "_utils": "{couch_httpd_misc_handlers, handle_utils_dir_req, \"../share/couchdb/www\"}",
    "_uuids": "{couch_httpd_misc_handlers, handle_uuids_req}",
    "favicon.ico": "{couch_httpd_misc_handlers, handle_favicon_req, \"../share/couchdb/www\"}"
  },
  "attachments": {
    "compressible_types": "text/*, application/javascript, application/json, application/xml",
    "compression_level": "8"
  },
  "admins": {
    "admin": "hidden"
  },
  "query_server_config": {
    "os_process_limit": "25",
    "reduce_limit": "true"
  },
  "vendor": {
    "name": "The Apache Software Foundation",
    "version": "1.6.1"
  },
  "replicator": {
    "connection_timeout": "60000",
    "db": "_replicator",
    "http_connections": "20",
    "max_replication_retry_count": "infinity",
    "retries_per_request": "10",
    "socket_options": "[{keepalive, true}, {nodelay, false}]",
    "ssl_certificate_max_depth": "3",
    "verify_ssl_certificates": "false",
    "worker_batch_size": "500",
    "worker_processes": "4"
  },
  "couch_httpd_oauth": {
    "use_users_db": "false"
  },
  "ssl": {
    "port": "6984",
    "ssl_certificate_max_depth": "1",
    "verify_ssl_certificates": "false"
  },
  "log": {
    "file": "../var/log/couchdb/couch.log",
    "include_sasl": "true",
    "level": "info"
  },
  "view_compaction": {
    "keyvalue_buffer_size": "2097152"
  },
  "query_servers": {
    "coffeescript": "./couchjs.exe ../share/couchdb/server/main-coffee.js",
    "javascript": "./couchjs.exe ../share/couchdb/server/main.js"
  },
  "daemons": {
    "auth_cache": "{couch_auth_cache, start_link, []}",
    "compaction_daemon": "{couch_compaction_daemon, start_link, []}",
    "external_manager": "{couch_external_manager, start_link, []}",
    "httpd": "{couch_httpd, start_link, []}",
    "index_server": "{couch_index_server, start_link, []}",
    "os_daemons": "{couch_os_daemons, start_link, []}",
    "query_servers": "{couch_query_servers, start_link, []}",
    "replicator_manager": "{couch_replicator_manager, start_link, []}",
    "stats_aggregator": "{couch_stats_aggregator, start, []}",
    "stats_collector": "{couch_stats_collector, start, []}",
    "uuids": "{couch_uuids, start, []}",
    "vhosts": "{couch_httpd_vhost, start_link, []}"
  },
  "httpd": {
    "allow_jsonp": "false",
    "authentication_handlers": "{couch_httpd_oauth, oauth_authentication_handler}, {couch_httpd_auth, cookie_authentication_handler}, {couch_httpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}",
    "bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
    "default_handler": "{couch_httpd_db, handle_request}",
    "enable_cors": "true",
    "log_max_chunk_size": "1000000",
    "port": "5984",
    "secure_rewrites": "true",
    "socket_options": "[{recbuf, 262144}, {sndbuf, 262144}]",
    "vhost_global_handlers": "_utils, _uuids, _session, _oauth, _users"
  },
  "httpd_db_handlers": {
    "_all_docs": "{couch_mrview_http, handle_all_docs_req}",
    "_changes": "{couch_httpd_db, handle_changes_req}",
    "_temp_view": "{couch_mrview_http, handle_temp_view_req}",
    "_view_cleanup": "{couch_mrview_http, handle_cleanup_req}"
  },
  "database_compaction": {
    "checkpoint_after": "5242880",
    "doc_buffer_size": "524288"
  },
  "couch_httpd_auth": {
    "allow_persistent_cookies": "false",
    "auth_cache_size": "50",
    "authentication_db": "_users",
    "authentication_redirect": "/_utils/session.html",
    "iterations": "10",
    "require_valid_user": "true",
    "secret": "ec2364797d3c4da0a1d89e1d44d92e99",
    "timeout": "600"
  },
  "couchdb": {
    "attachment_stream_buffer_size": "4096",
    "database_dir": "../var/lib/couchdb",
    "delayed_commits": "true",
    "file_compression": "snappy",
    "max_dbs_open": "100",
    "max_document_size": "4294967296",
    "os_process_timeout": "5000",
    "plugin_dir": "%locallibdir%/plugins",
    "uri_file": "../var/run/couchdb/couch.uri",
    "util_driver_dir": "../lib/couch-1.6.1/priv/lib",
    "uuid": "13d376d472463626725ae62b7f14ef18",
    "view_index_dir": "../var/lib/couchdb"
  },
  "compaction_daemon": {
    "check_interval": "300",
    "min_file_size": "131072"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have **require_valid_user = true** you should set **WWW-Authenticate = Basic realm="administrator"**. This will prevent you getting logged out.

```
[httpd]
WWW-Authenticate = Basic realm="administrator"
...
[couch_httpd_auth]
require_valid_user = true
```

Comment: And can you explain why? Also, what does the administrator value refer to?

Comment: I guess its by design. I got that from their documentation, If you look in etc/local.ini. Sorry I can't help beyond this. Note: I am using couchdb 2.0 on windows.